# redirect to a new page once file upload is finished

Tags: php

I have got the following php file for my file upload, how do I redirect to a new page once the file is finished upload, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
echo <<<_END
<html>

<title>PHP Form Upload</title></head><body>
<form method = 'post' action='testupload.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
Select File: <input type='file' name='filename' size='10' />
<input type='submit' value='Upload' />
</form>


_END;


 if($_FILES)
{
$a = uniqid();
   $saveto =  $a.".jpg";;
 // $name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'],  $saveto);
  $typeok = TRUE;

  switch($_FILES['filename']['type'])
   {
     case "image/gif": $src = imagecreatefromgif($saveto); break;

       case "image/jpeg":
         case "image/pjpeg":  $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($saveto); break;

      case "image/png": $src = imagecreatefrompng($saveto); break;

       default: $typeok = FALSE; break;
    }


     echo "Upload image '$saveto'<br/><img src='$saveto' />";
  }
  if ($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 2000)
     {
      echo "Error: file is too big" . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     }

  echo"</body></html>";

   ?>
```

Comment: Much better than your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370392/direct-to-a-new-page-once-finish-uploading-php)

Answer (score 2):

Perform the redirection as normal in your `action`, i.e. `testupload.php`.

Answer (score 2):

put your if statement for _FILES before everything, and when upload is finished (move_uploaded_file probably), put this code

```
header("Location: newlocation.php");
```

Comment: Plus HTTP 1.1 requires an absolute URI for Location headers, even if nobody seems to comply.

Comment: [Looks like](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) June 1999, absolute URI requirement is here: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: Welcome to the world of browsers, where over-tolerance is usual :) "Why to think about it?" Well, for you, just in the rare case if someday you come across an application that "obstinately" obeys the standards and doesn't accept your relative URI's...

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but it give me this error, Cannot modify header information - headers already sent